# Branch.io architecture query

Tags: branch.io

I have the following requirement and based on the branch docs I cannot get myself a straight answer.

We want to enable deep links that if the user has the app installed that it uses them and if not redirects to download then redirects.

If the user is on a desktop they get redirected to a page to download app.

We want to control all the actual deep linking using react navigation config and wanted to know how we can pair the two!?  The guides are very poorly written and makes understanding the flow a nightmare.

Some guidance and suggestions on how best to accomplish this would be great.

P.s.  are the links generated that when app found it takes the prefix and replaces with appname:// ??

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement for deep linking can be handled with Branch, you can set the URI schemes of the apps under the [link settings](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/default-link-behavior) of your Branch dashboard and also mention your app on PlayStore/Appstore for the user to download the app when clicked on the link.Similarly you can add the redirection URLs for the scenarios when your link is clicked on a desktop.

Alternatively you can use our React SDK to create links with all these [link properties](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link) and even more. More details [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native#section-create-deep-link).

The handling of the deep link data and redirecting the user to the desired page can be found [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native#section-read-deep-link).

If you wish to know more about how Branch passes data through to the app and attributes app sessions, check [this](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/branch-matching-overview).